# How to make MainPage.xaml.cs talk to MainActivity.cs using interface

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to do these classes share some data, I read that the right way to do that is through an interface but MainPage.xaml.cs doesn't recognizes the "link". What I need to add in MainPage.xaml.cs to make it work?

Class1.cs:

```
namespace interfaceWebnav
{
    public interface IPortableInterface
    {
        object Test();
    }
}
```

MediaService.cs

```
using interfaceWebnav;

namespace ComprarMusicas
{
    public class MediaService : Java.Lang.Object, IPortableInterface
    {
        public object Test()
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
...
...
using interfaceWebnav;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IPortableInterface))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
     [Activity(Label = "Comprar Músicas", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true,ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity :  global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            ............
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
   }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        // here I need to know what SomeMethod() from MainPage.xaml.cs is saying
    }

}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs (I commented out some of my tries of make it work):

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
// using interfaceWebnav;

// [assembly: Dependency(typeof(IPortableInterface))]

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object resultado = DependencyService.Get<IPortableInterface>().Test();
    }
}
```

At MainPage.xaml.cs, visual studio says about SomeMethod:
 "A namespace can't contain members as fields or methods directly."

About "Get IPortableInterface" it says:

"The name of type or namespace IPortableInterface can't be find(are you missing an using directive or an assembly referency?)"

Comment: instead of calling MainActivity.cs add new class to your android project and inherite that from interface then call this using Dependency service from MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: question tittle and your post is completely different

Comment: Your `DependencyService` write in a wrong way, please refer to the [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction#Overview) document  for more detailed information.

Answer (score 3):

Add Class says MediaService.cs in your android project inherit it from IPortableInterface

```
public class MediaService : Java.Lang.Object, IPortableInterface
{
    public void Test()
    {
        // your android platform specific implementation
    }

}
```

In the MainPage.cs file your invoking dependency service

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public bool foo = true; //just an example

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    //I suppose invoking any event lets says button click calling interface dependency service of android project
    void Button_Clicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        object resultado = DependencyService.Get<IPortableInterface>().Test();
    }

}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: can you please take a look at the modifications I've made and give a little help with the conclusion?

Comment: @ÉderRochaBezerra what will be problem right now? is that working or not

Comment: I updated the question, see the new code, the problem now is at MainPage.xaml.cs, visual studio says about SomeMethod: "A namespace can't contain members as fields or methods directly."

About Get IPortableInterface it says:

"The name of type or namespace IPortableInterface can't be find(are you missing an using directive or an assembly referency?)"

Comment: The snippet you're showing doesn't seem to be directly responsible for the error.This is how you can CAUSE the error? show me complete code. including all namespace and upto last curly braces.

Comment: I'm new on this, what I wanted actually was simply set the variable as static to be accessible on others views. It was the sulution, not an interface LOL.